# how to deploy custom github branch on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

Is there a way to select a custom branch to deploy ?
I do not seem to be able to select a branch and it takes the default main branch

thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Vercel automatically deploys any commit you push to a branch.

You can also customize which branch is used as the Production Branch in the project settings:
[Go to Project Settings > Git > Production Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGsqZ.png)

Comment: Seems no any way to trigger this action by manual function. Only support push the branch to github repos can working. Can't understand this design.

Comment: You can now manually trigger deployments using "deploy hooks", found in Settings > Git > Deploy Hooks. Create one that points to your branch & navigate to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to deploy a branch without pushing a commit, you can use `vercel-cli`.
To re-deploy the preview environment:

```bash
vercel --force
```

To re-deploy the production environment:

```bash
vercel --prod --force
```

If you haven't setup `vercel-cli` yet check [Vercel's CLI document](https://vercel.com/docs/cli)

Source: [Deploy An App Without Pushing An Empty Commit](https://github.com/jbranchaud/til/blob/master/vercel/deploy-an-app-without-pushing-an-empty-commit.md)

Answer (score 2):

I am able to view the latest commit made on my repo by heading to `Deployments` tab then click the three dots of a specific commit that you want to deploy. Choose the `Redeploy` option from the drop down list.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:
add the code to **vercel.json** file in root directory:

```
{
    "env": {
        "BRANCH": "custom-branch"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vercel-deploy": "if [ \"$BRANCH\" != \"main\" ]; then echo \"Cannot deploy from $BRANCH branch\"; exit 1; fi"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems no way to choose a branch when creating a new project. But, after deployment first, you can change Production Branch in Settings/Git configuration.

Comment: True, but after changing the branch in Settings/Git, you still have to do git push to the branch; there is no other way to trigger its build.